# using <?php brackets inside an echo statement

Tags: php, html

I am trying to to use fwrite and put some html codes in a file through php but I also want to include php brackets while writing into the file. Somehow this doesn't work. Here's the code.I just wanted to ask how can i write php statements to a file using `fwrite`.

```html
<?php
$File = fopen('myfile.txt' "w"); 
fwrite($File, '<html>
<body>
  <p id='test'>Test</p>
  <?php 
     echo 'hey';
?>
  </body>
</html>
')
fclose($File);
?>
```

Comment: You should surround your HTML and PHP code with single quotes, since using double quotes would cause issues. e.g if `$var = "foo"` then if you do this `"<?php echo  $var"`, this would write `<?php echo foo` to the file. Take a look a my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing like this:

```
echo "<?php hey ?>"
```

Comment: use " (quote) when you want to include multiple line in string

Comment: your welcome , happy coding and please vote up if i'm helpful

Comment: behaviour of single quote and double quote is different in php

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `fopen` has syntax error: it should be `$File = fopen('myfile.txt', "w");` **not** `$File = fopen('myfile.txt' "w");`. Try this:

```
$File = fopen('myfile.txt', "w");
fwrite($File, "<html>
        <body>
        <p id='test'>Test</p>
        <?php
        echo 'hey';
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
        ");
        fclose($File);
```

the output in `myfile.txt` will be:

```
     <html>
        <body>
        <p id='test'>Test</p>
        <?php
        echo 'hey';
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
<?php
  $File = fopen('myfile.txt',"w"); 
  fwrite($File,
    "<html>
    <body>
    <p id='test'>Test</p>"
    .'hey'.
    "</body>
    </html>
    "
  );
  fclose($File);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to been opening the PHP string near `id='test` which is the problem here.

Instead, assign all your HTML to a variable to make things easy.

Surround the PHP string with single quotes `'` and use double quotes `"` in the HTML.

```
$html = '<div id="test">
           <p class="paragraph">This is foo</p>
           <p class="paragraph"> and this is ' . $bar .'</p> // You can concatenate with . following a PHP variable 
         </div>';
fwrite($file, $html);
fclose($file);
```